# How can I better populate two arrays in a class?

Tags: c#

I need to populate a class of SubTopics that looks like this:

```
public class SubTopic
{
    public int[] SubTopicId { get; set; }
    public string[] Description { get; set; }
}
```

So far I have the following code to insert in the description but not yet the SubTopicId.

```
var description = new List<string>();
description.Add("afds).");
description.Add("afas.");
...
...
description.Add("aees.");

new SubTopic { Description  =  description.ToArray()}
```

Can anyone think of a simple way for me to populate the SubTopicId with numbers 1,2,3 .. etc and also is there maybe a better
way that I can populate the SubTopic class. Something better than adding to a list and then converting to an array?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to use an array for storage? Will the content of the lists change over time?

Comment: Why not use a Dictionary<int, string>?

Comment: I picked an array as what I do later is I take the contents of the class and then convert it to a JSON object and store it as a string. Is this kind of thing possible with Dictionary? If so then that might be a great solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use class and array initializers:

```
var subTopic = new SubTopic
{
    SubTopicId = new[] { 1, 2, 3 },
    Description = new[] { "afds).", "afas.", "aees." }
};
```

Comment: Your way looks fine but I would like to automate the generation of numbers as they are always in sequence. Is there a way I could do this without typing in { 1, 2, 3 } ?   Thanks, Jen

Comment: @Jennifer, you could do this: `SubTopicId = Enumerable.Range(1, 15).ToArray()`

Answer (score 2):

```
var description = new[]{"afds).", "afas.", /*...,*/ "aees."};
var subTopic = new SubTopic { 
    Description  =  description,
    SubTopicId = Enumerable.Range(1, description.Length).ToArray()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all inline if you want:

```
var x = new SubTopic {
  Description = new string[] { "a", "b" },
  SubTopicId = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < SubTopicId.Length; i++)
{
    SubTopicId[i] = i;
}
```

As for the strings array, as has been suggested, you can do it inline.